# How to write wp_mail without header

Tags: wordpress, php

Is it okay to write wp_mail without header?

the usage of the function is 
`<?php wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments ); ?>`

**Q: Can I use it like this ?** `<?php wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message); ?>`

Comment: yes it can be used, but then it will use default header.

Comment: You can do. were You tried without headers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, If you check the text below  the parameter `$headers` says its `(string or array) (optional)`

```
$to
(string or array) (required) The intended recipient(s). Multiple recipients may be specified using an array or a comma-separated string.
Default: None

$subject
(string) (required) The subject of the message.
Default: None

$message
(string) (required) Message content.
Default: None

$headers
(string or array) (optional) Mail headers to send with the message. (advanced)
Default: Empty

$attachments
(string or array) (optional) Files to attach: a single filename, an array of filenames, or a newline-delimited string list of multiple filenames. (advanced)
Default: Empty
```

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail#Parameters

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use it :

```
<?php wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message); ?>
```

$headers and $attachments are empty by default (they are optionnal).

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use like this

```
<?php wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message); ?>
```

$headers is an optional parameter